# Como registrar automaticamente Target Groups no Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-aws, elastic-beanstalk

Tenho uma aplicação no Elastic Beanstalk que quando alterei a capacidade dele e configurei o health check começou a dar `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`. Depois de um tempo vi que isso tinha alguma ligação com o Target Groups.

Fui lá e adicionei a instancia no Target Groups e resolveu.

Porém, rodei um analytics terceiro que faz requests e percebi que o ELB subiu uma nova instancia e depois anulou a anterior, ou algo parecido. Dessa forma tirou o registro do Target Group.

Onde posso automatizar isso? Ao subir uma nova instancia adicionar no Target Group?
Nunca deu esse problema, será que alguma coisa foi desfeita e agora estou tendo que adicionar manualmente mas existe a forma de ser automático?

Comment: Porque o Downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui identificar o problema que estava ocorrendo.

Por algum motivo acabou criando um Target Group novo, então acabou ficando 2 Target Groups para o mesmo ambiente.

No Target Group antigo, ao criar ou deletar uma instancia nova, ele automaticamente atrelava o ambiente, mas no Target Group novo não.

Em `EC2` > `Load Balancer` > `meu-ambiente` > `Listeners`, a porta 80 estava direcionando para o Target Group antigo e a porta 443 estava direcionando para o Target Group Novo.

**Solução:** Editei e defini tanto o listener da porta 80 quanto da 443 para o Target Group antigo que ja fazia tudo automaticamente.